# PHP date greater than todays date not working

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I have looked all over and I can't work out why this isn't working. I am trying to compare today's date to a date I set. I want to know if the date is greater than or equal to todays date. For some reason my code isn't working and I can't figure out why. This is the code I have:

```
    <?php 
 $date_now = date("d-m-Y");      
             
if (($date_now >= date("01-12-2020"))) { ?>

            greater than 1st

   <?php  } else { ?>

            not greater than

   <?php  } ?>
```

I am sure it is something simple but I have looked all over and I can't work out what I am missing.

Comment: Because it doesn't compare them as dates, it compares them as numbers. They're nothing but strings and they gest cast into integers before the comparison. Since casting stops at the first non-numerical sign, it ends up comparing `24 >= 1`. A more reliable way is to use the [datetime class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php). The objects can be compared using operators.

Answer (score 0):

You could try like this with `\strtotime()` [native php function](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.strtotime.php):

```
<?php
$date_now = date("d-m-Y");

// now compare date as timestamp
// 1606780800 (1st december 2020) is greater than 1606176000 (24th november 2020)
if (\strtotime($date_now) >= \strtotime(date("01-12-2020"))) {

    echo 'greater than 1st';

 }  else {

    echo 'not greater than';
  }
```

`\strtotime` give you the ability to retrieve [timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timestamp) from an date (as text or locale notation).